# Using Checklists & Radios to input information into Databases

Tags: php

So basically what I want to do is to grab the selected checklist element(s) and send their "name" to the database.  I would also like to do the same with the radios.  Here is the code:

```
<?php       
        $user_files_directory = 'uploads/unused_images/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/';

        if (file_exists($user_files_directory)) {

        $dir_handle = @opendir($user_files_directory); 

        while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 

        if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 

        continue; 

            echo "
            <div id=\"image_container\">
                <div id=\"unused_images_selector\">
                    <img src=\"uploads/thumbs/unused_images/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/$file\" alt=\"Test\">
                </div>
                <div id=\"checkbox\">
                        <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$file\">
                </div>
            </div>
            "; 
        }
        // Close 
        closedir($dir_handle); 

        } else {
            echo    "<p>
                        You have not uploaded any images.
                    </p>";
        }
    ?>
```

A post for this exists:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
```

And here is the rest:

```
function create_new_page($page_name, $album_name, $file, $file1, $file2) {
        $page_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($page_name));
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pages` VALUES ('', '$album_name', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$page_name', '$file2', '$file3', '$file')");
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

Everything but the radio/checklist works, any help is greatly appreciated, I know the code may not be the best but that's because I've not done much PHP, just want some working code though so not worried too much right now about issues here and there.

EXTRA:  $file is the name of the images that are being placed in the page (it's a selection area for which images a user would like to use) and so I was hoping that, with using $file it would create the image name in the MYSQL database but it instead writes "array".

Comment: What does `$file = $_POST['file'];` return?

Comment: Where would I put this?  I already have this in my document but how do I determine what it returns as when I put it on the homepage nothing showed up after putting it there, not sure if that's useful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood the workings of a HTML form and the way to extract it in PHP.
You are setting the `name` attribute to the actual file name (which is *not* "file") and are trying to extract the POST param with name `file`. The way to do this would be to name the checkbox `file[]` (as in an array of files) and set the `value` attribute to the file name. Your PHP code may remain the same.

Modify your checkbox code as follows:

```
<div id=\"checkbox\">
        <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$file\" />
</div>
```

Since you already have the following:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
```

`$file` will give you an array of file names. You can then process that data as you require.

**EDIT :** Since the OP has modified the question.

You want to store multiple image names into the database so you need to fire multiple `INSERT` statements. You could probably loop on the `$file` variable and build your queries.

Use something on the following lines:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

foreach ($file as $filename) {
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tblImages vcImageName VALUES (?)");
    $query->bind_param("s", $filename);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($result);
    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, would the same thing need to be done in the radios too?

Comment: You'll also need to put the `<input>` inside of a `form` or use HTML5 attributes. Unless you use javascript to post data.

Comment: Oh, it is within a form, this input is just right in the middle and it's quite expansive

Comment: @user1907323 You would need to do the same for your checklist and radios. However the radios would return only one single value so use `radio` and *not* `radio[]` in that case. If the answer has helped you please upvote and mark as answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would rate up but I need 15 reputation and I don't yet but nonetheless I am very grateful for your support on the issue! :)

Comment: The one thing I am slightly confused on, slightly off of the main point though now, but the array is confusing as, since I used $file to determine the filename of the image stored on the server, I assumed that all of the images selected via the checklist boxes would input their filename into the database but it simply submits the word "array" is this an easy fix that I'm just missing or what?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by sending just the image name. You have a checklist of multiple files. How do you want them stored in the database? Update your question with your requirements so I can help you by modifying my answer.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I should have said it beforehand, the files are already being handled (ie named) on upload, I'm just trying to retrieve their id to send to the server now.  Thanks so much for your help and I'm sorry I'm not helping all that much with explaining!

Comment: Let's extend our discussion over a private chat. I want to know what exactly your requirements are. Go to http://zippychat.com/room/ygirv  and use password `user1907323_php`.